# CMake compile cpp project for windows

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cmake, clion

Good afternoon!
I have a C ++ project in Macos with CLion, it works perfectly but when I compile it only creates the files prepared for Mac (or so I think). I want to transfer the project to a windows so that my colleagues can use it without having a mac. Is it possible to configure the CMakeList so that a file is created that can be used in windows?

I give you the configuration that I have in CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(serviceToSQL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(serviceToSQL main.cpp tinyxml2.cpp)
add_library(tinyxml2 tinyxml2.cpp tinyxml2.h)
add_library(tinyxml2::tinyxml2 ALIAS tinyxml2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: No change would be needed for windows. There is nothing in your CMakeLists.txt that is OS specific. Although like on your macOS these libraries need to be installed somewhere and MS Windows unlike other OSs does not have a default location to install lib files or headers ... So the user may have to tell CMake where these are installed on windows.

Comment: If your colleagues want to build the project on their own e.g. using visual studio, they should be able to use this exact `CMakeLists.txt` on their end; some different command line options are required to set up the project properly though. If you need some target system dependent settings in the cmake project, you could use `if(WIN32)` to check for a windows target.If you want to build the windows program on your Mac though,you'll need to find yourself a cross compiler and pass the info about this compiler to cmake when setting up a new build dir;this info is imho best put in a toolchain file